# Hide or Change CSS and Script files address from source code?

Tags: css, firebug

I have a website and I want hide the CSS and script files address from source, when user clicked right and press "view source", CSS and script files address were changed. (as well as in firebug).
Like google! please go to google.com and press right click, then "Inspect Element With Firebug", see Style in right box. You will see "www.google.com #2 (line 9)" for example! and you won't see any address for CSS files!
How is this possible?

Comment: I can clearly see all style definitions and links in googles html page. Also the style definitions are shown in an inspection console. There is nothing you can do to prevent that. The browser has to know the definitions, otherwise it cannot use them. And if it knows them it shows them.

Comment: I guess again one of those attempts to keep 'intellectual property' hidden? Don't. If your code is worth being seen and inspected then be proud of it and show it. If it is not, then make it better instead of trying to hide-publish it.

Comment: Huh? Yeah, you can easily see the source address of the CSS on google's page. The styles are all contained within the page itself - i.e on line 8 if you're in Aus. You can't see the filename because the page is automatically generated. I.e it could be index.php, index.aspx or pretty-much anything else actually, considering the power of url re-writing.. If your site contains client-side code it can be viewed. All styles on the page can also be viewed. Simple as that. Spend your time improving or obfuscating your code. You cannot hide it.

Comment: Folks, why do you downvote the question? Look, it has generated a lot of interest. If the wording is confusing (and it can be), help the author by editing it or asking something. I guess the real question was, "No <link> elements for CSS in the source; present links in Inspect Element; how come?" I tried to answer that version.

Comment: I have down voted the question, because, being able to see the source code of css and js files are the most beautiful thing in the world. You can learn many things by reading beautifully implemented/designed web pages by digging into the source code. I hope there will never ever be any way to crypt/hide css/js source. That's just bad.

Comment: @Muhammet Can Then Google must be fundamentally evil with its generated code and implicit CSS ;). Seriously, I think the author asked us _how_ he could reproduce that, not whether he _should_ do that or not. A lot of us believe he shouldn't and that's useless anyway. And it's still our unsolicited subjective opinion on how someone should manage the stuff he creates. I'm afraid that does NOT answer his legitimate question, which was, "How could I do the same."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you meant viewing the page source and not seeing any style links there, that's because Google uses some JavaScript framework, perhaps GWT: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/ . You can see a lot of JavaScript gibberish on the page, right? That JavaScript creates  all the style elements etc. in the DOM. And you indeed can see the resulting style definitions when inspecting the elements, be it Firefox or Chrome.

You can do the same. But that design is quite different from classic HTML + JavaScript.

But others are right, you can't hide anything that way, and you shouldnt. It's security by obscurity at best.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cant prevent users from seeing these files. They can see these files as well as can also download them if they want.

All you can do is to minify these files using some kind of minifier like [JS Minifier](http://fmarcia.info/jsmin/test.html) for JavaScript code.

Comment: If this is possible, what solution do you propose?

Answer (score 0):

You can place your css in inline  tags.  Simply copy/paste the contents into your .html document in a ... block.  Then you won't have an external .css file.

The advantage is that you save an http hit.  The disadvantage is that you have to download the full css every time because you can't cache it.

You can also minify your css which will obfuscate it to a certain extent.  But you can never really hide css from someone who downloads it.